# SSAS - Creating named calculation from different tables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssas

I am having troubles when i want to create a named calculation from two different tables.

I have the table "`CallesDim`" with an `id(PK)` and a description and the table "`UbicacionesDim`" with an `id (PK)`, another id (`FK` to "`CallesDim`") and a description:

--

**CallesDim**

- id PK
- Descripcion VARCHAR

--

**UbicacionesDim**

- id PK
- CalleId FK to id from CallesDIM
- Altura INT

--

I want to concatenate "Descripcion" from "CallesDim" with Altura from  "UbicacionesDim".

I try doing this:
`CallesDim.Descripcion + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,UbicacionesDim.Altura)`
but i am having the following error:

`the multi-part identifier "CallesDim.Descripcion" could not be bound`

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a named calculation you can only access columns from the table that it is defined on.

Which record of the other table should it take in case it would accept columns from other tables? How should it join? All this cannot be configured.

If you need to join two (or more) tables, you can define a named query that can contain joins and access as many tables as you like. A named query can contain everything that you can state in a single select statement.